# can somebody explain why floating action button not working . I am a newbee to this

Tags: flutter

the floating action button is not defined is shown on vs code I am unable to understand my self I was just following a youtube tutorial.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(  
  MaterialApp(
  home:Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('flutter'),
      centerTitle: true , 
    ),
    body:Center(
      child:Text("welcome to flutter") ,)
    ),
    floatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton(
      child: Text('click') 
    ), 
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `floatingActionButton` property on `MaterialApp`.
It is only available for a `Scaffold`.

Try like this:

```dart
void main() =>
      runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('flutter'),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Text("welcome to flutter"),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () => print("FloatingActionButton Clicked"),
                  child: Text('click'))),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the floatingActionButton property on MaterialApp.
It is only available for a Scaffold. but if you want same functionality you Text Button like this.

```
  TextButton(
               child:Container(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                        colors: [
                                          Color.fromARGB(250, 255, 166, 158),
                                          Color.fromARGB(
                                            250,
                                            250,
                                            243,
                                            221,
                                          ),
                                        ]))),
                            onPressed: () {
                             
                            },
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`floatingActionButton` requires `onPressed` attached. and Need to be within `Scaffold` Widget.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () { //anything you need to do after tap  },
  tooltip: 'Shopping Bag',
  child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
),
```